# Как показывать инфоблоки с определенным свойством (сортировка по городам)?

Tags: битрикс, сортировка

Я создал псевдо доску объявлений на сайте.

На странице детального просмотра я вывел инфоблок с рекомендуемым товаром и сделал его рандомным, но мне нужно чтобы показывались объявления по городам. Как это реализовать?

Я вижу такой выход: создать дополнительное поле и вбивать в него город, при добавлении элемента, вот только как выводить по значению этого поля я не могу понять, в методе сортировки я прописываю RAND, он выводит рандомом, а что прописать для моей цели?

```html
 
 
<div style="width: 960px;"> <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:news",
"web20",
Array(
 "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_AS_RATING" => "rating",
 "TAGS_CLOUD_ELEMENTS" => "150",
 "PERIOD_NEW_TAGS" => "",
 "FONT_MAX" => "50",
 "FONT_MIN" => "10",
 "COLOR_NEW" => "3E74E6",
 "COLOR_OLD" => "C0C0C0",
 "TAGS_CLOUD_WIDTH" => "100%",
 "USE_SHARE" => "Y",
 "SHARE_HIDE" => "N",
 "SHARE_TEMPLATE" => "",
 "SHARE_HANDLERS" => array("delicious","mailru","facebook","twitter","lj","vk"),
 "SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN" => "",
 "SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_KEY" => "",
 "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
 "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
 "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "Krovlya",
 "IBLOCK_ID" => "66",
 "NEWS_COUNT" => "10",
 "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
 "USE_RSS" => "N",
 "USE_RATING" => "N",
 "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
 "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
 "USE_FILTER" => "N",
 "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
 "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
 "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
 "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
 "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
 "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
 "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
 "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array("TAGS","DATE_CREATE"),
 "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(),
 "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
 "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
 "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
 "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
 "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
 "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array(),
 "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(),
 "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
 "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
 "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
 "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
 "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
 "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
 "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
 "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
 "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
 "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
 "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
 "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
 "CACHE_NOTES" => "",
 "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
 "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
 "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
 "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
 "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
 "PAGER_TITLE" => "Кровельные материалы",
 "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "Y",
 "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
 "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
 "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
 "SEF_FOLDER" => "/Krovlya/",
 "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
 "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
 "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => Array(
  "detail" => "#ELEMENT_CODE#.html"
 ),
 "VARIABLE_ALIASES" => Array(
  "detail" => Array(),
 )
)
);?></div>
 
<div style="text-align: center; width: 960px;"><b> 
<br />
   </b></div>
 
<div style="text-align: center; width: 960px;"><b>Рекомендуем</b></div>
 
<div style="text-align: left; width: 960px;"> <?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("=PROPERTY_CITY" => "Астана");
?> <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:news.list",
"",
Array(
 "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
 "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
 "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "Sayding",
 "IBLOCK_ID" => "64",
 "NEWS_COUNT" => "1",
 "SORT_BY1" => "PROPERTY_CITY",
 "SORT_ORDER1" => "RAND",
 "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
 "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
 "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
 "FIELD_CODE" => array("TAGS"),
 "PROPERTY_CODE" => array("PROPERTY_CITY"),
 "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
 "DETAIL_URL" => "/sayding/#ELEMENT_CODE#.html",
 "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
 "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "j F Y",
 "SET_TITLE" => "N",
 "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
 "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
 "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
 "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
 "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
 "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
 "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
 "CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
 "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
 "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
 "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
 "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
 "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
 "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
 "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
 "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
 "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
 "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
 "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
 "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N"
)
);?></div>
 
<div style="text-align: left; width: 960px;"></div>
```

Comment: Уберите из вопроса лишнюю информацию. Дополните фрагментом кода.

Comment: какая тут лишняя информация по вашему? я описал суть своей проблемы, что еще?

Comment: Излагайте только факты, необходимые для ответа. Нам не важно зачем вы что-то сделали (если это не важно для ответа), какого рода товары у вас и подобные вещи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать фильтр.
Указываем свойство в котором указан город, сам город. И в вызове компонента
`"FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter"`

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("=PROPERTY_CITY" => "Астана");
?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list",
    "",
    Array(
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "Krovlya",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "66",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "1",
        "SORT_BY1" => "RAND",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
        "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
        "FIELD_CODE" => array("TAGS"),
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(),
        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "/Krovlya/#ELEMENT_CODE#.html",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
        "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N"
    )
);?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43719/discussion-on-answer-by-mihanik71------).